# Getting error message error_description=invalid_scope, when trying to authenticate via amazon cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to aws and I am learning it. I am using AWS cognito to authenticate login to my application. But I am getting the following message in the URL:

http://localhost:8080/hotel/#error_description=invalid_scope&state=glEBNLLJrVTiLb0NSTO9Q35IYNrwpg9Z&error=invalid_request

I searched it on google but got no help. So, I am stuck with this problem. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the TokenScopesArray passed to the CognitoAuth method of amazon-cognito-auth.js file, matches with OpenID Connect scopes of Hosted UI of the User Pool that you might have created.

Comment: How to know what scopes are valid for the Hosted UI? For example, I'm passing `openid profile email` standard scopes but still getting the `invalid_scope` response.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your code

```
TokenScopesArray : ['openid', 'email'],
```

is matching what you have  in
Amazon Cognito ->User pools ->hotel-booking-Users->App client: xxwebxx ->
Edit Hosted UI ->
Edit Hosted UI Info  "OAuth 2.0 grant types"

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have the '**profile**' scope enabled in your AWS Cognito configuration.

App Client -> Hosted UI configuration screen
[image]